# Global const variables not assigned when constructor is executed

Tags: c++, constructor, mfc, visual-c++-6

`MY_GLOBAL_CONST` is not assigned when I try to use it in `ProblemClass::ProblemClass()`. Why? How to fix that? I am working on an old VC6 MFC project.

**SomeClass.h**

```
#include "ProblemClass.h"
class SomeClass  
{
private:
    ProblemClass m_problemClass; //created on the heap

public:
    SomeClass();
    ~SomeClass();
}
```

**ProblemClass.h**

```
class ProblemClass
{
public:
    ProblemClass();
    ~ProblemClass();
}
```

**ProblemClass.cpp**

```
#include "ProblemClass.h"
const CString MY_GLOBAL_CONST = _T("User");//Also tried to put that line in ProblemClass.h without luck
ProblemClass::ProblemClass()
{
    CString foo = MY_GLOBAL_CONST; //MFC-Runtime assertion fails, MY_GLOBAL_CONST  is not assigned yet 
}
ProblemClass::~ProblemClass(){}
```

**Update:**

After some further investigation I can confirm that `SomeClass`is also instantiated in a global context. So, Paul Sanders is absolutely right by saying *"happening here is two global initialisers being executed in the wrong order"*.

Comment: Do you have a global variable of type `ProblemClass` or `SomeClass` in a source file other than `ProblemClass.cpp`? The order of initialization of globals in different translation units is undefined.

Comment: I don't use instances of those classes globally. Only `MY_GLOBAL_CONST` is global. So far, `SomeClass` is only used once and `ProblemClass` is only used in `SomeClass`

Comment: When and where do you use `SomeClass`? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Also, if you catch the crash in a debugger, what does the call-stack look like?

Comment: The application is huge. `SomeClass` appears very early in the call stack while the `MY_GLOBAL_CONST` isn't assigned yet. We use those global consts (inside namespaces) very often and never had such problems. But we never used them in the startup of the application yet. At least on the modern project, not the VC6 one I have to deal with right now. I will provide the minimal example later.

Comment: If you don't see `main` or `WinMain` on the call stack, then you are in fact creating an instance of `SomeClass` somewhere as a global variable, or a member thereof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
const CString MY_GLOBAL_CONST = _T("User");
```

with:

```
const TCHAR MY_GLOBAL_CONST [] = _T("User");
```

The latter construct doesn't require any run-time initialisation and `MY_GLOBAL_CONST` can therefore be relied upon in other initialisation code (because what is surely happening here is two global initialisers being executed in the wrong order).

Comment: I will give that a try soon! Your conclusion sounds very valid.

Comment: Note, that this changes runtime behavior, whenever a `CString` object is created from `MY_GLOBAL_CONST`. It can no longer invoke the copy c'tor, and needs to re-calculate the length. This means additional runtime overhead, and breakage, in case `MY_GLOBAL_CONST` contains embedded NUL characters.

Comment: @IInspectable In the context of the original question, how could `MY_GLOBAL_CONST` ever contain a NUL character?

Comment: The question is asking about the initialization order of objects with static storage duration. The specific type of the object failing to initialize is not important. Changing the type to solve the issue, however, changes program behavior. If you don't feel like that is an important detail to note, then don't. I don't care, but a future visitor might.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you missed the `static` keyword with you declaration. My recipe for gloabl variables which need to be initialized outside of the class.

#### Header File

```
class ProblemClass
{
public:
    ProblemClass();
    ~ProblemClass();

private:
    static const CString MY_GLOBAL_CONST; // declaration in the header file
}
```

#### Source File

```
const CString ProblemClass::MY_GLOBAL_CONST = _T("HELLO_WORLD"); // Initialization here outside of class

ProblemClass::ProblemClass()
{
    CString foo = MY_GLOBAL_CONST; //MFC-Runtime assertion fails, MY_GLOBAL_CONST  is not assigned yet 
}

// everything else
```

Comment: In the example, `MY_GLOBAL_CONST` is not a member of `ProblemClass`.

Comment: @PeterRuderman OP tried having it as a member, I went this way in light of that. There is no mention of the global not being of part the class as a requirement. It's just one way to go.

Comment: I am very aware of constants being part of a class. But in this case, we use global ones. Actually they are wrapped into namespaces